# Configure SSRS 2008 on Windows Server 2008 R2 - Blank Page

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, sql-server-2008, ssrs, ssrs-2008

I think I have everything set up for reporting services to work.

But when I go to the report manager URL it just says "home" at the top, and there are no options to click properties,etc.  The page is mostly blank.

I'm thinking maybe windows integrated security isn't turned on,  but I'm not sure how to check or change it.

Comment: can you post your rsreportserver.config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps [How to: Install and Configure Reporting Services on Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839480(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: I actually looked at that before asking.  I made sure all the IIS stuff was installed.  Maybe I should reinstall SSRS.

Comment: Other than the installation stuff in IIS, you will need to make sure you have configured IIS correctly.

Comment: It's strange, I don't see any virtual directories listed in the IIS management console.  I'm not sure how that's possible since SRSS config does mention virtual directories that it's using.

Comment: check this out http://blogs.technet.com/andrew/archive/2007/12/04/sql-server-2008-reporting-services-no-longer-depends-on-iis.aspx.. looks like SSRS 2008 had no dependency on IIS and hence you may not be able to see the virdir's. You will need to configure SSRS using Reporting Services Configuration Tool

Comment: just a quick update, i install SSRS 2008 on my WIN2K8R2 machine and SSRS 2008 does not require IIS for configuration or management.